# How can I find external DNXCore Libraries

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx

Now that DNXCore is finally available on Linux I try to code some projects for this target but:

How can I find nuget libraries that are compatible with DNXCore?

Comment: Same question here. Do you have found an answer? In my case I'd like to use NewtonSoft JSON.net and NetMQ libraries.

Comment: I haven't found an answer yet. Newtonsoft has an updated library. I have seen that work. But the rest of the libraries is a pain.

Comment: Ok. I think .netCore is too young and we have wait until external libraries are transposed. Thank you!